# Apply an domain filter if an condition is correct in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i wanna apply an domain filter in odoo just if an condition is true
in my case i want to apply the filter just if the current user is equal to Administrator

Comment: Can you give a minimal example?

Comment: for example a filter to display tree view content only if the current user is an administrator

Comment: You can use groups for that `groups="base.group_system"`

Comment: Did you try it ?